# How to have multiple search keys using a file name

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a database wherein the files are named abcd100.00b, abcd101.00b,...

I need a code where when the user enters abcd separate then 100 to 110 all the files with the name abcd and in the range 100 to 110 should get displayed.

These are rinex files with the naming convention like `iisc001.10h`. There are multiple files ranging from `iisc001.10h` to `iisc100.30h` and so on. I want to be able to search `iisc` (first 4 characters) then 001 to 100 - all files within this range need to be displayed as tabular form.

The following code can display only the first four characters, how do I implement this?

```
    <?php

//capture search term and remove spaces at its both ends if the is any

     $searchTerm = trim($_GET['keyname']) ;

//check whether the name parsed is empty

     if($searchTerm == "rinex_file")
     {
       echo "Enter name you are searching for.";
       exit();
      }
      if($searchTerm == "rinex_file")
     {
      echo "Enter name you are searching for.";
      exit();
      }

//database connection info

    $host = "localhost"; //server
    $db = "rinex"; //database name
    $user = "m"; //dabases user name
    $pwd = "c"; //password

//connecting to server and creating link to database

    $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pwd, $db);

//MYSQL search statement

    $query = "SELECT * FROM rinexo WHERE rinex_file LIKE '%$searchTerm%'";

     $results = mysqli_query($link, $query)  ;

/* check whethere there were matching records in the table
by counting the number of results returned */

     if(mysqli_num_rows($results) >= 1){
     echo '<table border="1">
     <tr>
     <th>rinex version</th>
     <th>program</th>
      <th>date</th>
     <th>maker name</th>
     <th>maker number</th>
      <th>observer</th>
      <th>agency</th>
     <th>position_X_Y_Z</th>
      </tr>';
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)){
     echo '<tr>
     <td>'.$row['rinex_version'].'</td>
     <td>'.$row['pgm'].'</td>
      <td>'.$row['date'].'</td>
      <td>'.$row['marker_name'].'</td>
        <td>'.$row['marker_no'].'</td>
         <td>'.$row['observer'].'</td>
        <td>'.$row['agency'].'</td>
      <td>'.$row['position_X_Y_Z'].'</td>

     </tr>';

       }
     echo '</table>';

      }else{

       echo "There was no matching record for the name " . $searchTerm;


        }
```

Comment: Post some sample data with expected result

Comment: Are you trying to say that you need a pagination support for this code?

Comment: these are rinex files with the naming convention like this iisc001.10h there are multiple files ranging from iisc001.10h to iisc100.30h n so on all i want is to be able to search iisc( first 4 characters) then 001 to 100 all files within this range needs to be displayed as tabular form.

Comment: What is your problem? what is **NOT** working correctly here? The whole query, just the range part, or what?

Comment: the query works fine, only the range is the issue, i want three lables where the user has to enter the first four chars(iisc) the other two to enter the digits for example 1000 to 1100, al files in this range shoud get displayed

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use regular expression:

```
SELECT * 
FROM rinexo 
WHERE rinex_file regexp '^$searchTerm([0][0-9]{2}|100)\.'
```

In case if $searchTerm='iisc' then this code will fetch records which started from "iisc001." and up to "iisc100.". You need to quote $searchTerm (php function preg_quote), so no special characters will not getting into query.

See more for regular expression in mysql on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

But reqular expression can work no so fast, if possible create addtional column where will be placed integer value which you need, for example:

```
1 for iisc001.10h
2 for iisc002.10h
100 for iisc100.10h
```

search term (before digits, as "iisc") also make sense move to separate column and create index for them, and searching will be going only on them.

Yet one way:

```
select rinex_file, 
       substr(rinex_file, 1, 4) as prefix,
       substr(rinex_file, 5, locate('.', rinex_file)-5) as digits,
       substr(rinex_file, -3, 2) as suffix,
       substr(rinex_file, -1) as postfix
from rinexo
where substr(rinex_file, 1, 4) like 'iis%'
  and substr(rinex_file, 5, locate('.', rinex_file)-5) like '0%'
```

Comment: Sorry, was an extra '%' in sql query. It has been removed, please try again.

Comment: thank u, the exact file name is in this convention iisc0030.11d, i need to be able to search iisc separate, 0030 separate and 11 and d separate. this m unable to do

Comment: Why don't add a new columns in the table for each of these parts? Of course it will be require a redundant space for storage, but for performance will be optimal. For the query without any additional columns, I have added a new query to the answer.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot, this helps but the problem is in the html template wen i enter iisc it displays all issc files or if i enter only 0030 it displays all the corresponding files now it is only display the last field rinex_field. may b m goin wrong with the html code but still il keep trying . now that only the last field i.e, rinex_file is getting displayed is ther a way ti hyperlink it so that i can download the file??????/